# After shifting the website to another server. Products are showing out of stock

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3.3, inventory, cataloginventory

After shifting the website to another server. Products are showing out of stock

I found the error while uploading the database file.

```
 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)))
```

## 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation for

Comment: i think update or delete permission not provide database user

Comment: https://prnt.sc/soqovs Privilege given

Comment: It means you don't have privileges to create the trigger with root@localhost user..

`CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost FUNCTION fnc_calcWalkedDistance` >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315660/1227-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-for-thi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the SQL data dump file, you need to remove all definer tags from the SQL data dump file before moving.

Remove all `DEFINER=` entries from SQL import file.

`DEFINER` privileges are different from the GRANTS, the user is not allowed to execute `DEFINER statements`.

**OR**
(assuming user/host service is allowed to run definer privileges)
`CREATE DEFINER = **control_panel_username**@localhost FUNCTION ...................`

Comment: (If you are using another method of importing "shifting", then you need to give us more details).

Comment: only one "DEFINER="is mentioned as I see on the database file. I've already removed that before uploading the SQL file. Website is running bur all products are showing OUT OF STOCK.

I got the above error while uploading SQL file.

Comment: Since you already also confirmed GRANTS, have you tried indexing Magento 2?    `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Yes, I did the indexing and cache flush

Comment: I have no other idea, other than verifying that stock quantities are actually imported in the database.  Not sure about all the tables, but `cataloginventory_stock_status` has fields like `is_saleable` and `quantity`.  Also verify if `inventory_stock_1` exists and has data.

Comment: Thanks solved. Remove all DEFINER= entries from SQL import file. Then re-uploaded the file and indexing

Comment: Thank you, I assume you double checked and reimported :)